# "Check Component Dependency" without any details on conflict

Tags: magento, magento2

I have tried to add the trust pilot extension following [this guide](https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021194414--Trustpilot-s-free-Magento-2-plugin-download-install-and-configure-it#install-plugin-magento-marketplace).

However, when it comes to the readiness check in the extension manager, there is a failure on "Check Component Dependency" without any details on the conflict. The guide seems to indicate that the error would be shown but that's not the case (please see image below)

There does not appear to be anything in the exception log and I'm not sure where to check for the details regarding the conflict. Any recommendations on where to look would be really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue, what solved it for me was to edit user.ini in Magento root. The memory limit should be set to 2G.

Comment: Many thanks for your help JolandaK, that's worked now.